# network connection always detected on handset, even with no network

Tags: android, networking

I am checking the networking connection in Android, on a real handset. It always shows “Internet Connection Present”, even when I close the network connection in “Settings -> Location -> Use wireless network -> off” and “enable GPS statelites -> off” and also disable wifi.

I am using the following code:

```
  private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // test for connection
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Internet Connection Present");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I have set permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using real handset or emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Settings->Location->Use wireless network (off) and Use GPS satellites (off)' as mentioned above are settings for determining location, not disabling access to the internet.

In order to cut off access to the internet completely, try Airplane mode (Settings -> Wireless & network settings -> Airplane mode)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemServic(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) 
    {
        Log.w("tag", "couldn't get connectivity manager");
    }
    else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * THIS IS FUNCTION FOR CHECKING INTERNET CONNECTION
     * @return TRUE IF INTERNET IS PRESENT ELSE RETURN FALSE
     */
    public boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**This is working in my project and tested on device also**

If you want to check GPS Provider availability then try this code

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = null;

        if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        } else if ( lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Not available", 3000).show();
        }

        if(provider != null) {


            lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 30000, 100, this);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location != null) {
                currentGeopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                if(currentGeopoint != null) {
                    currentaddress = getAddressFromLatitudeAndLongitude(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: for gps there is another code...as this code only checks network provider availability.