# how to check internet connectivity in the device in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, connectivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check wifi or 3g network is available on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262781/how-to-check-wifi-or-3g-network-is-available-on-android-device)
>   [Check the Internet Connectivity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094123/check-the-internet-connectivity-in-android)

I am using an Android device and I am disabling the WiFi connection in my device.Now I have an application which uses Internet and whenever the application runs I want to show a simple message i.e a Toast message telling that "No Internet connection" rather than the crashing of the application.

How to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828263/network-connection-always-detected-on-handset-even-with-no-network/5828311#5828311)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094123/check-the-internet-connectivity-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167153/checking-if-programm-has-the-internet-over-wifi

Comment: As others pointed out, there are already questions with correct answers that can be found within a minute. So **-1** for no research effort.

Comment: Interesting how this question came back from -3 in a second. Meanwhile a 8 month old question of mine suddenly got downvoted twice with no reason stated. Very mature. Also what's the point? Want me to downvote without stating a reason in the future so I'm protected from that kind of behaviour? Great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public final boolean isInternetOn()
 {

  ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService
  (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))

  {

 return true;

  }

  else     
  return false;

 }
```

Comment: The `else if` block is useless, you can directly return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if( ! ( cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())  )
    {
        android.util.Log.e(LOGTAG, "No connectivity to send information...");
        return;
    }
```